# Modifying the output of ls command

Tags: bash

I'm modifying the output of the `ls` command. I have achieved a long line of code that does all I want, but I feel like it could be improved a lot, in many ways, so I am asking for your opinion about it. I will explain each command so you're sure to know what I wanted to do with it.

Here is my long line of code:

```
ls -l |
sed 's/total/                                            C FILES.c/' | 
cut -b 45-100 | 
grep -e "\.c" | 
sed 's/C FILES.C/\nC FILES\n/' |
sed 's/[0-9]//' |
sed 's/[0-9]//' | 
sed 's/[0-9]//'
```

[image: Result]

1. `ls -l` displays "total: " + a number, and then displays 1 file per line.
2. `sed 's/total/'                                            C FILES.c/` This long part is supposed to replace the "total" line with a title, and as you will see in the next command, I had to indent it this way, so it is in the same row than then names of the files displayed by `ls -r`. Numbers will be taken care of in a latter command.
3. `cut -b 45-100` cuts all the stuff that is before the names of the files. As I did put 45 spaces before "C FILES.C" in the last command, it will cut them and show only the 55 next characters. (55 is large enough to contain any file name I use).
4. `grep -e "\.c"` deletes the files that don't end with .c. As the title, C FILES, is not a c file, I had to write it with a .c suffix so it doesn't disappear when using the grep command.
5. `sed 's/C FILES.C/\nC FILES\n/'` deletes the .c suffix and adds some newlines characters to separate the command line, the title, and the list of files.
6. The second command replaced "total" by the "C FILES" title. But it didn't replace the number that follows "total", so this number is still here and I want to get rid of it. The command doesn't know what number it will have to delete, and it could be 1, 45 or even 666. I used 3 times the command `sed 's/[0-9]//` to delete 3 times a number between 0 and 9 (if there is one, else it will do nothing). If the number's length is higher than 3, there will still be some numbers, but I don't think I'll ever have a total of more than 999 so repeating 3 times this command may be enough. I tried `'s/[0-9][0-9][0-9]//` but it only works if the number's length is atleast 3. Else, it does nothing.

That's the best I could do. I tried to use the `ls` command with no option, but none of the following commands worked well after that and I didn't know how to make it output a title since there was no line to replace.

Any idea or advice on how to make it better and easier to read will be welcome.

Comment: Have you looked up or tried using `find` command?

Comment: add ls output and after parsing expected output

Comment: A good read - Why to not parse the output of `ls`, [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: No I haven't tried the `find` command, and I don't know what parsing means. thank's for the link.

Comment: Would the `find` command be more appropriate than `grep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your exact expected output (please provide that), my feeling is that you could replace all that with:

```
 echo C FILES; ls -1 *.c
```

For me that gives:

```
C FILES
foo.c
norm.c
readfile.c
size.c
thr.c
```

Is this the output you're looking for?  If not, what is?

Comment: That's exactly what I want, minus some little bugs that my code could have (I have 2 in mind). I just replaced `echo C FILES;` with `echo "\nC FILES\n"` to get the newlines and it is perfect. Didn't know about this ls option, I didn't find it in the man.

Comment: Why not `printf '%s\n' *.c` ?

Comment: wooo this is great too!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf your suggestion is clearly the correct way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the way I would do what it looks like you're doing feels rather simple but as far as I can tell, you want to simply list c files with the title "C Files"?

If I'm right then why not just do something like this:

```
echo "C Files" && ls *.c
```

of if you want it in a more "pipe"-able format:

```
ls *.c | cat <(echo "C Files") -
```

This second variant can then be sent to a file in the exact same format like this:

```
ls *.c | cat <(echo "C Files") - > output.txt
```

To get the same output but reordering the command input:

```
cat <(echo "C Files") <<< cat <(ls *.c)
```

Comment: using `ls` with no option lists files on 1 line and I want each file to be on a new line

Comment: Test this and see.. as soon as I pipe the output the files appear one per line. Tested on Debian and Ubuntu here. To add the spaces you can extend to this:
ls *.c | cat <(echo "") - | cat <(echo "C Files") - | cat <(echo "") -

Comment: yes that's nice too! i still prefer to have the command that displays the title in first position

Comment: This does put the title anywhere you want, unless you mean typing it in the first position? But I saw with using echo is that you can't send the output anywhere, the echo text is not included unless you put it inside cat. You can also just move the - character to change where the piped input goes

Comment: I meant that I prefer it when the command that displays the title is in first position

Comment: Makes sense, I just tried another method then as well. Will just update my answer to include it.